# Calculate for each row for how many columns is observation within top X%

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. For each row I would like to find out in how variables there is an `outlier` observation. For simplicity, let's assume that i define outlier as observation in the top (bottom) 5% of values recorded in each column.

In other words, I want to find out:

1. for each column find out the highest 5% of recorded values (return 1 if the observation is in the top 5% within given column, 0 otherwise)
2. row-wise sum
3. add the column identifying the `number of outliers per row` to the original dataset

How to do it in python in speed- and memory-efficient way?

**An example using R:**

Let's have dataset like:

```
   ID v1 v2 v3
1:  a  1  2  0
2:  b  2  3  0
3:  c  1  6  1
4:  d  3  1  2
5:  e  4  0  3
6:  f  5  2  5

# set up a reproducible example
library(data.table)
df = data.table(ID = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
                v1 = c(1,2,1,3,4,5),
                v2 = c(2,3,6,1,0,2),
                v3 = c(0,0,1,2,3,5))

# function to find out the outliers
outlier_detector = function(x, type = 'positive',tail = 0.05)
{
  if (type == 'positive')
  {
    x >= quantile(x,  1 - tail)
  }
  else if (type == 'negative')
  {
    x <= quantile(x, tail)
  }
}

# add two columns to the original dataset
# sum_out_positive - for each row calculates the number of columns where within top 5%
# sum_out_negative - for each row calculates the number of columns where within bottom 5%
df[,`:=`(
  sum_out_positive = df[,2:4][
    ,
    lapply(.SD, outlier_detector)][
      ,
      rowSums(.SD, na.rm = T),
      .SDcols = paste0('v', 1:3)],
  sum_out_negative = df[, 2:4][
    ,
    lapply(.SD, outlier_detector, 'negative')][
      ,
      rowSums(.SD, na.rm = T),
      .SDcols = paste0('v', 1:3)])]
```

Expected output:

```
   ID v1 v2 v3 sum_out_positive sum_out_negative
1:  a  1  2  0                0                2
2:  b  2  3  0                0                1
3:  c  1  6  1                1                1
4:  d  3  1  2                0                0
5:  e  4  0  3                0                1
6:  f  5  2  5                2                0
```

What would be the efficient way to implement this in python?
I know i could write a loop to iterate over all columns and for each observation return True/False based on whether the observation is an outlier and then perform the row-wise sum (using df.sum(axis = 1)).

But can i do this without creating another dataframe with the same size as the original data frame and then in the second step performing the summation? i.e. I would like to optimize the speed as well as the amount of memory required to perform the calculation.

**Bonus question:** How to improve my calculation in R?

**EDIT:**
I think i can do in python pandas something like:

```
(df.iloc[:, 1:3] >= df.iloc[:,1:3].quantile(0.95, axis = 0)).sum(axis = 1)
```

But is it the best way to go about it?

Comment: "# sum_out_negative - for each row calculates the number of columns where within top 5%" you mean the bottom 5% right?

Comment: @Erfan Yes, thank you for pointing it out. I fixed the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, maybe not the most elegant way, or the most optimal, but it works. Hope it helps:

```
# For each value column, indicate the outliers
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[f'{col}_outliers_pos'] = np.where(df[col] >= df[col].quantile(0.95), 1, 0)
    df[f'{col}_outliers_neg'] = np.where(df[col] <= df[col].quantile(0.05), 1, 0)

# Create lists for positive and negative columns 
pos_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'pos' in col]
neg_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'neg' in col]

# Calculate the sum of both negative and positive
df['sum_out_positive'] = df[pos_cols].sum(axis=1)
df['sum_out_negative'] = df[neg_cols].sum(axis=1)

# Drop columns we dont need to get correct output
df.drop(pos_cols + neg_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
  ID  v1  v2  v3  sum_out_positive  sum_out_negative
0  a   1   2   0                 0                 2
1  b   2   3   0                 0                 1
2  c   1   6   1                 1                 1
3  d   3   1   2                 0                 0
4  e   4   0   3                 0                 1
5  f   5   2   5                 2                 0
```